# Ошибка при загрузки библиотеки All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version specification

Tags: java, android

При попытки добавить библиотеку для рекламы от adMob

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.1.0'
```

подчеркивает красным

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И показывает ошибку

All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version specification

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: в ошибке сказано что нельзя использовать разные версии библиотеки и вам советуют использовать одну версию. попробуйте нажать на то что подчеркнуто и посмотрите что вам студия предложит.

Comment: `'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.1.0'` содержит внутри себя транзитивную зависимость. Может помочь `exclude module: 'appcompat-v7'` в опциях подключения admob библиотеки. А вообще можете оставить как есть. Это предупреждение. Ну и команду `gradlew app:dependencies` на всякий случай.

Comment: Подскажи пожалуйста, а где именно их вставить?

Comment: @Artsait думаю, так `implementation ('com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'){
        exclude module: 'appcompat-v7'
    }`. А `gradlew app:dependencies` - это команда вводимая в Terminal. О ней можно почитать  [тут](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/gradle_wrapper.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Ссылка на источник](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42374151/all-com-android-support-libraries-must-use-the-exact-same-version-specification)

Добавьте явно библиотеку, на которую жалуется студия (просит `com.android.support:customtabs:26.1.0`), но изменив её версию до вашей (28.0.0).

(P.S. Этой библиотеке `customtabs` понадобятся в итоге ещё 2 зависимости)

Объяснение: Вы можете быть смущены сообщением об ошибке, так как не используйте customtabs, но у вас конфликт. Ну .. вы не использовали его напрямую, но одна из ваших библиотек использует старую версию customtabs внутренне, поэтому вам нужно запросить ее напрямую.

В итоге вам надо добавить зависимости:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:customtabs:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
```

Не забудьте нажать «Синхронизация», чтобы Gradle мог перестроить график зависимостей и посмотреть, есть ли ещё конфликты.

Comment: Спасибо. Подчеркивание пропало, но теперь почему-то не компилирует, сейчас разбираюсь почему

Comment: @Artsait а что пишет?